# Create multiple column qualifiers in HBase using a loop

Tags: loops, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase

I would like to turn my row data into columns.

I have state and visit data as so:

```
State    Visit   Month
AZ       1023    06
NY       32234   06
OH       9821    06
NY       4564    07
KS       3232    06
MO       2322    06
AZ       222     07
```

I would like my data to look like this:

```
Month    AZ    KS    MO    NY     OH
06       1023  3232  2322  32234  9821
07       222               4564
```

My data is stored in HBase

The way I see it, I could filter the data by state and then append the new column to a new table.
I could do that with a small number of columns in Pig without a problem, but I think it would be silly to do it 50 times and I would rather use a loop. These would all be column qualifiers in the same column family, obviously.

I know Pig doesn't have loops. I have been trying to find a solution for the problem in Hive but no luck so far.

Is there a way to do this in Pig, Hive, Native Mapreduce, or in the HBase Shell?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this in Hive.  You can collect visits and month to a map and then reference the keys of the map as you new columns.  You'll need the `CollectUDAF` from [here](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse)

**Query:**

```
ADD jar /path/to/jar/brickhouse.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

SELECT month
    ,state_map['AZ'] AS AZ
    ,state_map['NY'] AS NY
    ,state_map['OH'] AS OH
    ,state_map['KS'] AS KS
    ,state_map['MO'] AS MO
FROM (
    SELECT month
        ,collect(state, visit) AS state_map
    FROM database.table
    GROUP BY month
    ) x
```

**Output:**

```
06    1023    32234    9821    3232    2322
07    222     4564     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am trying to avoid naming each state specifically. I would like the script to be completely automated instead of me having to explicitly name each column. I gave states as an example, but my real data would have thousands of columns so I cannot implement this solution.